# Comparing mongoose _id and strings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js application that pulls some data and sticks it into an object, like this:

```
var results = new Object();

User.findOne(query, function(err, u) {
    results.userId = u._id;
}
```

When I do an if/then based on that stored ID, the comparison is never true:

```
if (results.userId == AnotherMongoDocument._id) {
    console.log('This is never true');
}
```

When I do a console.log of the two id's, they match exactly:

```
User id: 4fc67871349bb7bf6a000002 AnotherMongoDocument id: 4fc67871349bb7bf6a000002
```

I am assuming this is some kind of datatype problem, but I'm not sure how to convert results.userId to a datatype that will result in the above comparison being true and my outsourced brain (aka Google) has been unable to help.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

Mongoose uses the mongodb-native driver, which uses the custom ObjectID type. You can compare ObjectIDs with the `.equals()` method. With your example, `results.userId.equals(AnotherMongoDocument._id)`. The ObjectID type also has a `toString()` method, if you wish to store a stringified version of the ObjectID in JSON format, or a cookie.

If you use `ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID` (requires the mongodb-native library) you can check if `results.userId` is a valid identifier with `results.userId instanceof ObjectID`.

Etc.

Comment: Docs for `.equals()`: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals

Comment: If you're already using `mongoose` you can just `require('mongoose').mongo.ObjectID` so you don't have to list any additional dependencies

Comment: Latest doc: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/ObjectID.html

Comment: I've found doc._id == stringId also works, though of course doc._id === stringId will be false because of strict type comparison. This is just easier to code by.

Answer (score 83):

`ObjectID`s are objects so if you just compare them with `==` you're comparing their references.  If you want to compare their values you need to use the `ObjectID.equals` method:

```
if (results.userId.equals(AnotherMongoDocument._id)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 38):

converting object id to string(using toString() method) will do the job.

Answer (score 20):

The three possible solutions suggested here have different use cases.

1. Use `.equals` when comparing ObjectId on two mongoDocuments like this

```js
results.userId.equals(AnotherMongoDocument._id)
```

2. Use `.toString()` when comparing a string representation of ObjectId to an ObjectId of a mongoDocument. like this

```js
results.userId === AnotherMongoDocument._id.toString()
```

Comment: What is the third possible solution?

Answer (score 15):

According to the above,i found three ways to solve the problem.

1. `AnotherMongoDocument._id.toString()`
2. `JSON.stringify(AnotherMongoDocument._id)`
3. `results.userId.equals(AnotherMongoDocument._id)`

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answers really limit what you can do with your code. For example, you would not be able to search an array of `Object Ids` by using the equals method. Instead, it would make more sense to always cast to string and compare the keys.

Here's an example answer in case if you need to use `indexOf()` to check within an array of references for a specific id. assume `query` is a query you are executing, assume `someModel` is a mongo model for the id you are looking for, and finally assume `results.idList` is the field you are looking for your object id in.

```
query.exec(function(err,results){
   var array = results.idList.map(function(v){ return v.toString(); });
   var exists = array.indexOf(someModel._id.toString()) >= 0;
   console.log(exists);
});
```

Comment: or a one-liner: `let exists = results.idList.filter(val => val.toString() === thisIsTheStringifiedIdWeAreLookingFor).length ? true : false`

Comment: @Zlatko i'm not a big fan of the new syntax but to each his own.

Comment: @Zlatko

`const exists = results.idList.some(val => val.toString() === thisIsTheStringifiedIdWeAreLookingFor)`

or

`const exists = results.idList.some(val => val.equals(someModel._id))`

Comment: @Zlatko all these years later, and guess what. I prefer your version to mine now. mind if i add it to my answer with proper attribution?

Comment: The price of progress :) Of course you can use the answer, it's purpose was to provide an alternative or help if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I faced exactly the same problem and i simply resolved the issue with the help of `JSON.stringify()` as follow:-

```
if (JSON.stringify(results.userId) === JSON.stringify(AnotherMongoDocument._id)) {
        console.log('This is never true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose from 5 to 6 migration guide:

"Mongoose now adds a `valueOf()` function to ObjectIds. This means you can now use `==` to compare an ObjectId against a string."

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#objectid-valueof

Answer (score 1):

Following can be used when trying to check whether an id of type string is present in an array of mongoose IDs

const id = new mongoose.Type.ObjectId(stringId);

const found = yourMongooseArray.some((element) => element.equals(id))

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that explains the issue and why it confusing for many. Only the first console log shows the object in its true form, and any other debuging/loging will be confusing because they look the same.

```
// Constructor for an object that has 'val' and some other stuffs
//   related to to librery...
function ID(_val) {
  this.val = _val;
  this.otherStuff = "other stuffs goes here";
}
// function to help user get usefull infos from the Object
ID.prototype.toString = function toString() {
  return `${this.val}`;
};
// Create new Object of type ID
const id = new ID('1234567');
console.log("my ID: ", id);  // my ID: Object { 
                             //    val: "1234567", 
                             //    otherStuff: "other stuffs goes here" 
                             // }

console.log("my ID: " + id); // my ID: 1234567
console.log(id === '1234567'); // false
console.log(id == '1234567'); // true
console.log(id.toString() === '1234567'); //true
console.log(`${id}` === '1234567'); // true
console.log(new ID('1234567') === id); // false
```