# ES6. how to compare correctly with === operator?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I the following function I am comparing two equal values  ( as displayed in the console , but the return is false ...

```
    function removeGroup(req, res, next) {
      const user = req.user;
      const found = user.groups.some((obj, idx) => {
        console.log('obj._id: ', obj._id);
        console.log('req.params.groupId: ', req.params.groupId);
        if (obj._id === req.params.groupId) {
          console.log('equal');
          user.groups.splice(idx, 1);
          return true;
        }
        console.log('not equal');
        return false;
      });
      if (found) {
        user.save()
          .then(savedTable => res.json(savedTable))
          .catch(e => next(e));
      } else {
        res.status(404);
        res.json({ message: 'Group Not Found' });
      }
    }
```

Here is the console .log result

```
    obj._id:  59109bc44ea63331151b9327
    req.params.groupId:  59109bc44ea63331151b9327
    not equal
```

Comment: Apparently they are not equal. Check their type (using `typeof`).

Comment: What @Bergi said, the difference between `==` and  `===` is the they have to be the same type. If `==` returns false, then there is something else going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing mongoose _id and strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11637353/1048572)? Unfortunately you haven't provided any info about those objects.

Comment: sorry ..   effectively user.groups.some((obj, idx) => {..} is referring to mongoose model. so I should use the toString() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice in JavaScript is to always use `===` instead of `==` to avoid coercion (implicit type conversion). For the record, you could also use `Object.is()` in ES6...

So why your code is not working? It is difficult to be assertive because you did not provide enough details in your question, but from what I saw in the comments, I think you will find a clear explanation below:

`obj._id` and `req.params.groupId` must be strictly equal in terms of **value** and **type**. This is great for primitive values (strings, numbers, booleans, ...), but the problem is that, in JavaScript, you cannot compare objects like so. In this language, objects are compared by **reference**. This means that an object will never be equal to another if it is not the same instance, even if it has exactly the same properties.

```js
let ref = {};

// false
console.log({} == {});
console.log({} === {});
console.log(Object.is({}, {}));

// true
console.log(ref == ref);
console.log(ref === ref);
console.log(Object.is(ref, ref));
```