# Can't read MongoDB Id format | displaying as bufferarray

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I am learner and student. I was trying to learn nodejs + mongoose. I was performing a comparison operation on mongoose id with two different collections.

**Model design**
Model one:

```
var ShowroomSchema = new Schema({ //ShowroomProduct/Item
    rug: { //product/itemDetails
        ...
        colourTags: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ...
    }
});
```

model two:

```
var ShowroomColourTagSchema = new Schema({ 
    name: String; 
})
```

I am storing the id's of **ShowroomColourTagSchema** in my **ShowroomSchema** and later trying to perform a loop to check with id's are equals so I will print the name of the color.

**function**

```
//colour tags
for (var index = 0; index < models.length; index++) { // model two id, name
      var element = models[index];

      for (var j = 0; j < item.rug.colourTags.length; j++) { // model one just array of object ids
         // for (var j in item.rug.sizeCategoryTags) {
         if (element._id.equals(item.rug.colourTags[j]._id)) {
              tags.push(element.name);
         }
      }
}
```

but I am facing issues in trying to make the condition work. I am trying to debug the code (from last 4-5hours). The watch expression is showing the colourTags from showroom as buffer array.

[image]

**Backend**

showroom_colour_tags collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c4310ada77350004cef56c"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T21:37:14.043+0000"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T21:37:14.043+0000"), 
    "name" : "Black", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c43114da77350004cef56e"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T21:37:19.378+0000"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T21:37:19.378+0000"), 
    "name" : "Grey", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c43170da77350004cef574"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T21:37:24.036+0000"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T21:37:24.036+0000"), 
    "name" : "Beige", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

showroom collection

```
{
    "rug" : {
       ...
        "colourTags" : [
            ObjectId("59c43170da77350004cef574"), 
            ObjectId("59c43114da77350004cef56e")
        ]
      ...
    }
}
```

How can I compare the ID's????! I will be very thankful for any suggestion. Thanks in advance. Let me know if you require more information. 
Peace :)

Comment: I am not an expert on mongoose, but you should be able to compare ObjectId with an `.equal()` method. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638106/3411075

Comment: remove _id from item.rug.colourTags[j]._id , colourTags is an array so you need to compare with position condition. e.g. if (element._id.equals(item.rug.colourTags[j]))

Comment: yes indeed... it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove _id from item.rug.colourTags[j]._id , colourTags is an array so you need to compare with position. your updated if condition will be.

```
if (element._id.equals(item.rug.colourTags[j]))
```