# Mongo ObjectIDs not equal to eachother

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
new Mongo.ObjectID('18986769bd5eaaa42cb565b1') == new Mongo.ObjectID('18986769bd5eaaa42cb565b1')
```

returns false

```
new Mongo.ObjectID('18986769bd5eaaa42cb565b1').toString() == new Mongo.ObjectID('18986769bd5eaaa42cb565b1').toString()
```

returns true

Is this a bug, a feature or do I need to only work with these using valueOf() and convert it back from string when I need to work with the database?

Comment: Two separate JavaScript objects are *never* `==` to each other.

Comment: You should take a look at this question, it might solve yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings  Basically they say that you need to use the equals method provided by the mongo library you are using

Comment: @Roger, please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @TylerClendenin Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings), it might solve yours. Basically, they say that you need to use the equals method provided by the mongo library you are using

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal as two objects are not equal to each other even if they contain the same information. You need to loop through all the properties and compare them individually.

```js
console.log({} === {});
```

example

```js
const obj1 = {id: 12345}
const obj2 = {id: 12345}

console.log(obj1 === obj2);

let same = true;
for(const prop in obj1){
  if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj1[prop] !== obj2[prop]){
      same = false;
      break;
  }
}

console.log(same);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because MongoDB is entirely based around JSON, so even if a particular piece of information is itself a string, Mongo still delivers it as a JSON object. Therefore, you need to parse it back into string form so that you can use it somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

```js
ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").valueOf() === "507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e" //true

ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e") === "507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e" //false

ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").valueOf() === ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").valueOf() //true
```