# Why this includes() return false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an API with nodejs and I have got the following dataset

```
[ { _id: 5ef054487c20460017dcbde8,
post_data: 'paw nisa dmme  vahi ponnaya',
likes: 2,
commentsCount: 0,
post_img: null,
isUserLiked: false,
usersLiked: [ 5eef7fc55de48230887f3aa3 ],
exp_date: 2020-06-27T00:00:00.000Z,
has_img: false,
user_id: [ [Object] ],
typology: 'post',
geometry:
 { pintype: 'Point',
   _id: 5ef054487c20460017dcbde9,
   coordinates: [Array] },
created: 1592808520819,
category: [],
createdAt: 2020-06-22T06:48:40.821Z,
updatedAt: 2020-06-22T07:29:00.148Z } ]
```

In there I have `usersLiked` array and I got the above results to `posts` variable and used the following code to change `isUserLiked`.

```
            posts.forEach((post) => {
                post.isUserLiked = post.usersLiked.includes(user_id)
            });
```

> The problem is `post.usersLiked.includes(user_id)` is always returing
> false

My mongodb looks like this .

[image]

I have already tried  `post.isUserLiked = post.usersLiked.includes(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user_id))` but it gives the same output ? What can be the problem here and how can I solve it ?

Comment: convert `Object ID` to string before comparison.

Comment: `id`, `user_id` and the content of `usersLiked` are objects of type [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). `.include()` uses the [`SameValueZero`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm which compares objects as objects. If they are not the same (`===`)  then the result will be `false`. Convert the ids to strings and then compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
post.isUserLiked = post.usersLiked.some(id => id.toString() === user_id)
```

If `user_id` is not a string use `.equals`. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638104/8443899

Comment: Why should OP call `.toString()` on `id`? And why not on `user_id`?

Comment: I thought `user_id` is a string.

Comment: Solved <3. I was able to solve the problem using `post.isUserLiked = post.usersLiked.some(id => id.equals(user_id)) `

Comment: @SuthuraSudharaka because you say "user_id" is a string would be better to use id.toString() === user_id since is a 2x faster then equals().

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem comes cause this dataset that you showed us, the `usersLiked: [ 5eef7fc55de48230887f3aa3 ],` has an array of something that's not an String.

Maybe if this ID, was an String, you can do then the `usersLiked.includes('ANOTHER STRING HERE')`

When i mean string, i mean should be like this: `usersLiked: [ '5eef7fc55de48230887f3aa3' ]`

Comment: I dont know user_id but im meaning the array of useersLiked, what you showd us, doesn't have the quotes as an String