# What is the correct way to do .has(), .get() and .set() for javascript Map() used in an ExpressJS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

javascript Map() has thrown me off. My question is about javascript Map() - `set`, `get` and `has()`. I thought I was an expert on it, but apparently not...

Situation: I have a 'global' map - a map saved on a different `.js` file that gets 'required'. This map's keys are the `_id` of MongoDB documents. The values of this map are class objects of `node-schedule` - an npm package. The value part can be ignored since my problem is with .get(), .has() and .set()

Here is my method that (fails to) cancel jobs:

```js
    cancelJob: async function (id) {
        console.log('---- inside cancelJob ---');
        console.log('id = ', id);
        console.log('map = ', config.map);
        console.log('map size = ', config.map.size);
        if (config.map.has(id)) {
            console.log('---- map has id ---');
            let job = config.map.get(id);
            console.log('job = ', job);
            await job.cancel();
            config.map.delete(id);
            console.log('---- deleted 1 from map ---');
        }
    },
```

The if statement always returns false. I previously tried the `.get()` and checked if the returned value is not `undefined`, but it was `undefined`.
let me share the console log of my server - resulting from the above code, after I do `.set()` and (failed to do) `.delete()` a couple of times:

```
id =  5f9c3b171a5d1b26089d60fe
map =  Map {
  5f9c3b171a5d1b26089d60fe => Job {
    job: [Function],
    callback: false,
    name: '<Anonymous Job 1>',
    trackInvocation: [Function],
    stopTrackingInvocation: [Function],
    triggeredJobs: [Function],
    setTriggeredJobs: [Function],
    cancel: [Function],
    cancelNext: [Function],
    reschedule: [Function],
    nextInvocation: [Function],
    pendingInvocations: [Function]
  },
  5f9c3b171a5d1b26089d60fe => Job {
    job: [Function],
    callback: false,
    name: '<Anonymous Job 2>',
    trackInvocation: [Function],
    stopTrackingInvocation: [Function],
    triggeredJobs: [Function],
    setTriggeredJobs: [Function],
    cancel: [Function],
    cancelNext: [Function],
    reschedule: [Function],
    nextInvocation: [Function],
    pendingInvocations: [Function]
  }
}
map size =  2
```

As you can see, map doesn't store (!?) the values to the same key slot? I am confused. I thought I learned that keys are unique, and that it should find the key... Please help me figure this out if you can :)

PS: I did `ctrl + F` on the ID value, and it turns out the ID string is the same for all the keys and the ID parameter.

---

Edit 1:
Here is the method that sets the map:

```
convertDocumentToScheduledJob: function (dbJob) {
 // prepare date and rule here...
 let j = schedule.scheduleJob(dbJob.recurrence == 'no-recurrence' ? date : rule, function () {
            // does stuff
        })
        config.map.set(dbJob._id, j);
}
```

I am using this `convertDocumentToScheduledJob` method to set/insert map key-value pairs. This whole thing is part of a `full-stack` web app, so there are multiple controllers that call these 2 methods, but I'm pretty sure those don't directly affect anything here. They just invoke these 2 methods.

Again, as seen in my `PS` message above, when I console log the `config.map`, it shows 2 map entries with the same keys. ~~Isn't that worrying?~~

---

Edit 2: @FelixKling solved this problem. The key was of data type, `Object`. I had to convert that to `String` to resolve this. Thank you.

```
    console.log('Type of job_id = ', typeof dbJob._id);
    let strId = JSON.stringify(dbJob._id);
    console.log('Type of strID = ', typeof strId);
    config.map.set(strId, j);
```

Comment: Key's are unique in a map, there is something missing here, can you show the code were your filling the map.

Comment: Sure. Here is the code that sets the map:
```javascript

    convertDocumentToScheduledJob: function (dbJob) {
 let j = schedule.scheduleJob(dbJob.recurrence == 'no-recurrence' ? date : rule, function () {
            // does stuff
        })
        config.map.set(dbJob._id, j);
```

Comment: What is `typeof dbJob._id` ?

Comment: @FelixKling nice catch. Turns out the typeof dbJob._id is `object`. Although it should have been a string. This is a major breakthrough. Thanks.
Edit: dbJob is a MongoDB document.

Comment: *"... it shows 2 map entries with the same keys. Isn't that worrying?"* Since it's not possible that a map has two entries with the same keys, the only conclusion can be that the keys must be different, which would be the case with a string object for example. But `dbJob._id` might be any object that possibly implements `toString`.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code to resolve this problem. It's very reasonable to check the data type of the map key and not to take a MongoDB string value to have the string datatype as granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FelixKling solved this question in the comments.

The key was of data type `Object`. I had to convert that to `String` to resolve this. Thank you.

Solution 1 (incomplete):

```
console.log('Type of job_id = ', typeof dbJob._id);
let strId = JSON.stringify(dbJob._id);
console.log('Type of strID = ', typeof strId);
config.map.set(strId, j);
```

- This eliminates the duplicated key bug. New map entries now properly replace the old map entry with the same key.
- The problem still persists when I invoke `cancelJob(id)` where the id is a basic string value. JSON.stringified string is different from regular string. (it has an extra double quote)
- MongoDB documentation shows a way to convert `._id` to regular string via the `.toString()` method. [Sources: [StackOverFlow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings); [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/)]

---

Solution 2:

```js
    convertDocumentToScheduledJob: function (dbJob) {
        // ...
        let strId = dbJob._id.toString();
    },
    cancelJob: async function (raw_id) {
        // ...
        let id = typeof raw_id == 'object' ? raw_id.toString() : raw_id;
    },
```

---