# MongoDB: How to find documents by value?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Two documents containing `ObjectId("6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf4")`

*Document 1*

```
  {
           "_id" : ObjectId("6144f66fb9543917f96fc"),
           "refId" : "ford",
            "template" : "6144f61cb96d772317f96f9",
            "fieldValues" : {
                "PDV" : [ 
                    "6126938cd24a8aa3d37b4992", 
                    ObjectId("6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf4")
                ]
            },
            "group" : ObjectId("6144f66fb96d7731917f96fd"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-17T20:11:27.440Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-20T15:06:26.146Z"),
            "__v" : 0
  }
```

*Document 2*

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6144f66fb96d77rr3217f96fc"),
            "refId" : "CCM",
            "template" : "6144f613296d7731917f96f9",
            "fieldValues" : {
                "DDB" : [ 
                    "6126938cd2448aa3d37b4992", 
                    "5443938cd2448aa3d37b4992", 
                    ObjectId("6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf4"),
                ]
            },
            "group" : ObjectId("6144f66fb96de431917f96fd"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-17T20:11:27.440Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-20T15:06:26.146Z"),
            "__v" : 0
 }
```

---

`ObjectId` that we looking for is always inside `fieldValues` but instead of `PDV` or `DDB` we will always have the different naming.

So we can't use this type of query:
`db.getCollection('products').find({"fieldValues.PDV":ObjectId('6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf4')})`

---

PS. This query should work only on DB, we can't afford to query all products and do calculation on backend there might to be a millions of products.

Comment: What are the exact conditions? May `ObjectId("6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf4")` appear **anywhere** in the document? Having an array (PDV or DDB) with elements of different data types will make it rather complicated.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried Domscheit, good point, I just updated my question.

Comment: "we can't afford to query all products and do calculation" - that's exactly what you did with your query.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit Yes, I removed this query example because it is wrong and just  confusing people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      kv: { $first: { $objectToArray: "$fieldValues" } }
    }
  },
  { $match: { "kv.v": ObjectId("6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf3") } },
  { $unset: "kv" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GbrUyrqT2NM)

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit thank you! This is a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

`db.products.find({'_id': ObjectId("6148a371c13a6a0be492ebf4")})`

The mistake in your code is that you used *key* instead of *_id*.

This way of writing it is much easier on the fingers though.

Comment: In your case _id is the key, but I don't have key in this array. Your solution will not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You'd think a solution like this would work but one reason why this may not is because you're trying to use `===` on an object. If you refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings), it might help if you use `.equals()` instead of `===`.