# Mongoose problem with object id "Cast to ObjectId failed for value"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, objectid

It's along explanation so to make it easier I'll call users x and y.

I got this code, which the intention is to the X (making the requests) add his ID into Y's pending requests as well as his own sent requests.

```
const postSendBBRequest = async (req, res) => {
  const userRecipient = await User.findById(req.params.id)
    const userSender = await User.findById(req.userId);
  const senderId = userSender.id;
  try {
    if (senderId == userRecipient.id) {
      res.status(406).json("You cannot have yourself as a brother")
    } else {

        userSender.sentBBRequests.push({senderId});
        await userSender.save();
            
        userRecipient.receivedBBRequests.push({senderId});
        await userRecipient.save();

        res.status(201).json("Brotheband request sent sucessfully")
      }
    } catch (ERR) {
        res.status(500).json({ Message: ERR.message });
    }
}
```

My test route on Postman is `/add/61b29bb33e775393ae369b79`

The problem is: I'm getting an error: `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ senderId: '61b29aef3e775393ae369b74' }\" (type Object) at path \"sentBBRequests\`

I thought maybe the problem was how I organized my Schema too:

```
 receivedBBRequests: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
  ],

  sentBBRequests: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
  ],

 brothers: {
    type: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      },
    ]}
```

There are too many points of failure I can't even come up with something to solve.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are comparing a string `senderId` with `userSender.id` which is an ObjectId, which is a type. This should help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
const senderId = userSender._id.toString();
const userRecipientId = userRecipient._id.toString();
```

this will allow you to convert the objectId  to string